# get lowermost left corner of an iamge and write text there

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I'm trying to get the lowermost left (x,y) coordinates of an image.
I'm doing that to be able to write a text in different-sized picture, in the left lowermost corner. Below is the code. Could you please help?

```
<?php
$white = imagecolorallocate($image2, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($image2, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image2, 0, 0, 0);
$textsize = 30;
$size = imagettfbbox($textsize, 0, $font, $text);
$xsize = abs($size[0]) + abs($size[2]);
$ysize = abs($size[5]) + abs($size[1]);
$image2size = getimagesize("image2.jpg");
$textleftpos = round(($image2size[0] - $xsize) / 2);
$texttoppos = round(($image2size[1] + $ysize) / 2);
imagettftext($image2, $textsize, 0, $textleftpos, $texttoppos, $white, $font, $text);
imagejpeg($image2, "image3.jpg");
?>
```

Comment: And which is the problem with your code?

Comment: The fact that I can center it, but not choose lowermost corner. As you can see from my multiple edits, I've had some variable mistakes. fixed them, but now the image is text is centered instead of in the left corner.

Comment: what exactly happens? No offense intended, but you need to become a bit more detailed in your error descriptions, they have a tendency to be a bit unclear. Please tell us the exact coordinates you are getting instead of the lowermost corner for example

Comment: @pekka-none taken:) it's an honor you guys take the time to answer ti newbie questions like these. These arew the coordinates I get: (50,152)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$indentfromedge = 5; // or whatever you want for an indent
$textleftpos = $indentfromedge;
$texttoppos = $image2size[1] - $ysize - $indentfromedge;
```

I think is what you're going for. Replace the two lines with `$text*pos` in them with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

On the left edge means an x-coordinate of 0
On the bottom edge means an y-coordinate equal to the height of the image minus the height of the text

So, say your text size is 30px:

```
$size = imagesize($img);
$x = 0;
$y = $size[1] - 30;
// assuming you're using GD1
imagettftext($image, 30, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, "sample text");
```

Comment: @reanimation-thanks, but I went with Brad's solution. Get a vote up anyhow!